# How put labels in the palette of leaflet instead of numeric values

Tags: r, leaflet

Here is an example from Shiny documentation.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rexp(100, 2), z = runif(100))
pal <- colorBin("PuOr", df$z, bins = c(0, .1, .4, .9, 1))
leaflet(df) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~x, ~y, color = ~pal(z), group = "circles") %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~z, group = "circles", position = "bottomleft") %>%
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("circles"))
```

I want to dispay in the palette:

```
level1, 
level2, 
level3, 
level4
```

instead of

```
0-0.1
0.1-0.4
0.4-0.9
0.9-1
```

I added the argument `labels=("level1", "level2", "level3", "level4")` to `addLegend`

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rexp(100, 2), z = runif(100))
pal <- colorBin("PuOr", df$z, bins = c(0, .1, .4, .9, 1))
leaflet(df) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~x, ~y, color = ~pal(z), group = "circles") %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~z, group = "circles", position = "bottomleft",
            labels = c("A","B","C","D")) %>%
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("circles"))
```

But nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `labFormat` argument, instead of labels. In `?addLegend` you have an explanation.
This works as you want:

```
library(leaflet)
  df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rexp(100, 2), z = runif(100))
  pal <- colorBin("PuOr", df$z, bins = c(0, .1, .4, .9, 1))
  
  labeller_function <- function(type, breaks) {
    return(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
  }
  
  leaflet(df) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addCircleMarkers(~x, ~y, color = ~pal(z), group = "circles") %>%
    addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~z, group = "circles", position = "bottomleft",
              labFormat = labeller_function) %>%
    addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("circles"))
```